# Why do I get this error? TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'points'

Tags: opencv, contour

```
contours2, hierarchy2 = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

((cx,cy),radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contours2)
area = radius * radius * np.pi
print (area)
```

I'm trying to get the area of this circle using this method

[image]

Why do I get this error? Thank you for taking time reading my post.

Answer (score 0):

`contours2` is a list. You should pass the contour you want to calculate the enclosing circle. Assuming you only have one contour,  the code below should work with no errors:

```
((cx,cy),radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contours2[0])
```

There is a function specifically to calculate the area of a contour:

```
area = cv2.contourArea(contour2[0])
```